# minimize function coefficents python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm having trouble choosing, and getting the minimize function to work in scipy. I have a 4th order polynomial defined below and the values for D,F, and Z. I need to solve for the coefficients a such that the function evaluates close to 0. Then this function can be used to model Z for D, and F inputs.

I've looked over the options here
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

Nelder-Mead, and BFGS algorithms aren't getting anywhere close to solving. I'm not sure if I am solving a function too complex for those methods, or I am doing something wrong. For the methods beyond that, I am not sure what I need to do to calculate the Hessian, and if there is a pythonic way to go about calculating it.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import scipy
def func(a,Z,D,F):
    return -Z + a[0]+\
        a[1]*F +\
        a[2]*(F)**2 +\
        a[3]*(1-a[6]/D)*(F) +\
        a[4]*(1-a[6]/D)**2 + \
        a[5]*(F)**3+\
        a[7]*((1-a[6]/D))*((F)**2)+\
        a[8]*((1-a[6]/D)**2)*((F))+\
        a[9]*((1-a[6]/D)**3)+\
        a[10]*((F)**4)+\
        a[11]*((1-a[6]/D))*((F)**3)+\
        a[12]*((1-a[6]/D)**2)*((F)**2)+\
        a[13]*((1-a[6]/D)**3)*((F))+\
        a[14]*((1-a[6]/D))*((F)**4)+\
        a[15]*((1-a[6]/D)**2)*((F)**3)+\
        a[16]*((1-a[6]/D)**3)*((F)**2)+\
        a[17]*((1-a[6]/D)**2)*((F)**4)+\
        a[18]*((1-a[6]/D)**3)*((F)**3)+\
        a[19]*((1-a[6]/D)**3)*((F)**4)
a0=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
res = minimize(func, a0,args=(56,35.0,.036),  method='BFGS')
print(res.fun,res.x)
```

Comment: One tip: If you use parenthesis for the whole long expression, then the characters `\` at the line ends are not needed.

Comment: There are an infinite number of solutions. For any value of `a[1:20]`, you can solve (analytically) for `a[0]` such that `f(a,Z,D,F) = 0` for fixed `Z`, `D`, `F`.

Comment: If you are trying to solve for where `f(a) = 0` for fixed `Z`, `D`, `F`, use `optimize.fsolve`. `optimize.minimize` is for *minimizing* the value of `f(a)`. Above, the minimum happens to be very negative, no where near zero.

Comment: Fitting and optimizing depends also on the initial guess of the parameters. Setting `a[6]=1` puts most terms in your equation to zero initially, so it's gonna be hard for the solver to come to results... Think about 'a0'!